# how to implode multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Attributes 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Attributes 3
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Attributes 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Attributes 3
                )
        )
)
```

I want its result

Attributes 2, Attributes 3

Attributes 1, Attributes 3

Comment: use foreach and array_column

Comment: May be `Attributes 1, Attributes 2` not correct. should be `Attributes 1, Attributes 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `foreach` and `array_column` you can did this thing. let array as `$arr` and use `implode()` for comma separated output.

Check this online: https://3v4l.org/Bdgh5

```
foreach($arr as $value){
    echo implode(", ", array_column($value, 'name'));
}
```

Let me know is it okey or not?

Comment: but i am getting error   "Call to undefined function array_column()"   in live server.

Answer (score 0):

It is another way, by using only foreach

```
$arr = array (
   0 => array (
        0 => array ( "name" => "Attributes 2"),
        1 => array ( "name" => "Attributes 3")
      ),
   1 => array ( 
        0 => array ( "name" => "Attributes 1"),
        1 => array ( "name" => "Attributes 3")
      )
);

foreach($arr as $value){
  foreach ($value as $key ) {
    echo $key['name'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me know it's ok or not